# How to fetch news from a db and print them on a PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, html, bootstrap-4

I want to fetch the last two news from a DB, then print them on a PHP page using a function.

The two news should be printed one next to the other.

This is what I've done so far, what am I doing wrong?

This is the problem:

[image]

```
<?php
    function getAllNewsHome(){
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "serverName");
        $connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $rsNewsHome = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");
        $newsHome = mysqli_fetch_all($rsNewsHome, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        mysqli_close($connection);
        for($i=0; $i < count($newsHome); $i++){
            echo "
                <div class='container'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'>
                            <h1>".$newsHome[$i]['title']."
                            </h1>
                            <p>".$newsHome[$i]['content']."
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'>
                            <h1>".$newsHome[$i]['title']."
                            </h1>
                            <p>".$newsHome[$i]['content']."
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What's your issue with the above code? Also, it'd be better to close the PHP tags, remove the `echo`, and output your HTML as HTML and echo using `<?= $var ?>`.

Comment: This is happening because you're printing it twice. What you'll need to do is put the the class within the loop, and then probably add a counter to decide if you need to close/open the container. Or you can do `$i++` in the middle of your loop between the two 6col divs to get the next result, but just make sure you check if the next iteration actually exists.

Comment: @aynber i've tried to print once, but then they would be one above the other and i need them to be side by side. Am i missing something in the echo?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do! Inside the `for($i=0; $i < count($newsHome); $i++)` loop it produces 2 divs, each containing the same "news" ( `$newsHome[$i]['title']`) *twice*!

You want the first div to contain the first article and the second div to contain the second article.

If you remove the second div within the for loop, it will create one div for each "news".

(And you will likely have to move the 2 outer divs (`<div class='container'>` and `<div class='row'>` outside the loop)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the easiest: increment `$i` inside of your loop, then make sure that it exists before you echo it out. This will allow you to keep your divs aligned:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($newsHome); $i++) {
    echo "
                    <div class='container'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                                <h1>" . $newsHome[$i]['title'] . "
                                </h1>
                                <p>" . $newsHome[$i]['content'] . "</p>
                            </div>";
    $i++;
    echo "
                            <div class='col-xs-6'>";
    if(array_key_exists($i, $newsHome)) {
        echo "<h1>" . $newsHome[$i]['title'] . "
                                </h1>
                                <p>" . $newsHome[$i]['content'] . "</p>";
    }

    echo "
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ";
}
```